# Making seekable videos with Firefox WebRTC Media Recorder

Tags: firefox, html5-video, getusermedia, web-mediarecorder

I have been attempting to capture a web cam videos on a web page. I have noticed that the method I am using is not creating a video which is seekable. I'm not sure if this is because I am doing something wrong, or if there is a bug in Firefox.

Is there a way to fix, or to work around this issue? I am imagining worse case scenario I may need to fix this issue with a tool like FFmpeg.

http://jsfiddle.net/2gkvddme/14/

```
var recordVideo = {
    videoOptions: {
        audio: true,
        video: true
    },
    init: function(options){
        this.startMediaStream()
    },
    startMediaStream: function(){
        this.capture = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(this.videoOptions);
        this.capture.then(this.mediaStreamSuccess.bind(this));
        this.capture.catch(this.webcamErrorHandler);
        this.el_video = document.querySelector('video');
        this.el_Message = document.querySelector('.message');
    },
    webcamErrorHandler: function(e) {
        this.el_Message.innerHTML = 'error: ' + e;
    },
    mediaStreamSuccess: function(mediaStream) {
        this.mediaStream = mediaStream;
        this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(this.mediaStream);
        this.mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = this.mediaStreamCapture.bind(this);
        this.el_video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.mediaStream);
        this.startVideoHandler();
    },
    startVideoHandler: function(){
        this.mediaRecorder.start(0); 
        document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', this.mediaRecordStop.bind(this));
    }, 
    mediaRecordStop: function(){
        this.mediaRecorder.stop();  
    },
    mediaStreamCapture: function(dataavailable) {
        this.mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = null;  
        var videoBlob = new Blob([dataavailable.data], {
            type: dataavailable.data.type
        });

        this.mediaStream.stop();
        var blobURL =  window.URL.createObjectURL(videoBlob);
        this.el_video.src = blobURL;
        this.el_Message.innerHTML = '<a href="' + blobURL + '">' + blobURL + '</a>';
    },
}

recordVideo.init();
```

Comment: There is an issue about this in bugzilla.https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1068001 

ffmpeg fixes this, but I'm having some audio sync problems